# How can set setTreeCellRenderer at JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable, treecellrenderer

I have this code to create a custom JXTreeTable and set a Custom CellRenderer.
This is the code:

```
    tableCatSpese = new TableAlbero(null);
    
    public TableAlbero(List<Conti> listaConti){
            setTreeTableModel(new RandomTextTreeTableModel(listaConti));
            this.setTreeCellRenderer(new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese());
            this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese());
        }
    }
    
    
    
    class RandomTextTreeTableModel extends DefaultTreeTableModel {
        public static NumberFormat decimalFormatter2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        DefaultMutableTreeTableNode Root = null;
        final String[] ColName = {"Acquisti/Vendite","Uscite","Entrate","Saldo"};
    
        RandomTextTreeTableModel(List<Conti>listaConti) {
            Root = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode();
            this.setRoot(Root);
            Conti contoTotale = new Conti();
            contoTotale.setTotale(0.0);
            contoTotale.setTotalePubblico(0.0);
            contoTotale.setEntrata(0.0);
            contoTotale.setUscita(0.0);
            contoTotale.setDescrizione("TOTALE");
            if(listaConti!=null){
                for (Conti conti : listaConti) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeTableNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(conti);
                    Root.add(node);
                    if(conti.getListaContiFigli()!=null){
                        for (Conti contoFiglio : conti.getListaContiFigli()) {
                            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(contoFiglio));
                        }
                    }
                    contoTotale.setTotale(conti.getTotale()+contoTotale.getTotale());
                    contoTotale.setTotalePubblico(conti.getTotalePubblico()+contoTotale.getTotalePubblico());
                    contoTotale.setEntrata(conti.getEntrata()+contoTotale.getEntrata());
                    contoTotale.setUscita(conti.getUscita()+contoTotale.getUscita());
                }
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeTableNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(contoTotale);
            Root.add(node);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column){
            return ColName[column];
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return ColName.length;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1) {
            try{
                if(arg1==0){
                    int numberElement = ((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getChildCount();
                    if(numberElement<=0)
                        return null;
                    Conti c = (Conti)((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getChildAt(0).getUserObject();
                    return new String(c.getDescrizione());
                }
                Conti c = (Conti)((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getUserObject();
                if(c==null)
                    return null;
                if (arg1 == 0) {
                    return c.getDescrizione();
                }else if (arg1 == 1) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getUscita());
                }else if (arg1 == 2) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getEntrata());
                }else if (arg1 == 3) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getTotale());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return arg0;
        }


public class CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese extends JLabel implements TreeCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4842418316518803090L;
    private Font fontTotale = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private Font fontNegativo = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        if (row== table.getRowCount()-1) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground( Color.RED );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount() && column !=3){
            setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            setFont(UtilitySwing.getTableFont());
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount()-1 && column ==3){
            //verifico il valore se negativo rosso
            //se positivo blu
            String valore = value.toString();
            if(valore.startsWith("-")){
                setForeground(Color.red);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }else{
                setForeground(Color.blue);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }
        }
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object aValue, 
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // Create a new panel where we will show the data.
        Conti conto = (Conti)((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)aValue).getUserObject();
        String text = conto.getDescrizione();
        panel.add( new JLabel( text ) ); // Actually show the data.

        // If the value is not null and is a tree node and a leaf then paint it.
        if( (aValue != null) && (aValue instanceof DefaultMutableTreeTableNode) && leaf )
        {
            if(row != tree.getRowCount()){
                //setForeground( Color.BLACK );
                setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
                //setFont(UtilitySwing.getTableFont());
            }else{
                //setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                setBackground( Color.RED );
                //setFont(fontTotale);
                
            }
            panel.setEnabled( tree.isEnabled() );
            panel.setBackground(Color.red);
            return panel;
        }
        // For everything else use default renderer.
        return defaultRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent( tree, aValue, selected, expanded, leaf,
                row, hasFocus );
    }
}
```

This is the graphic result:

[image]

How can you see int the first column, I can't see the complete String and I can't set correct background color.

How can I fixed this problem?

Comment: I'm sure that SwingX uses own Renderers

Comment: Ok and what is this Renderers?
Otherwhise, there is alterative object at JXTreeTable?